# what are the methods to create div dynamically and to show the array values in browser without any click

Tags: javascript

hi i want to display the set of array objects in the document,
how to create div or p tag dynamically and store the values without clicking anything

```
var myemp = [
    {
        name: "yuvaraj",
        age: 32,
        gender: "male",
        salary: 13000
     },
     {
         name: "raj",
         age: 22,
         gender: "male",
         salary: 40000
     }
]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Use javascript to create elements and add them to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myemp = [
            {
            name: "yuvaraj",
            age: 32,
            gender: "male",
            salary: 13000
            },
            {
            name: "raj",
            age: 22,
            gender: "male",
            salary: 40000
            }];

myemp.forEach(function(element, index){
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  para.innerHTML = "name: " + myemp[index].name + " age: " + myemp[index].age + " gender: " + myemp[index].gender + " salary: " + myemp[index].salary;
  return document.body.appendChild(para);
});
```

Comment: this solution will work for you without using any libraries such as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = '';
myemp.forEach(person => {
  result += `<p> Name: ${person.name} </p>`
  result += `<p> Age: ${person.age} </p>`
  result += `<p> Gender: ${person.gender} </p>`
  result += `<p> Salary: ${person.salary} </p>`
});

const element = document.getElementById('element');
element.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var myemp = [
                {
                name: "yuvaraj",
                age: 32,
                gender: "male",
                salary: 13000
                },
                {
                name: "raj",
                age: 22,
                gender: "male",
                salary: 40000
                }];

  $.each( myemp, function( key, value ) {

    $( "body" ).prepend( "<pre> Name :"+value.name+" </br> age : "+value.age+" </br> Gender : "+value.gender+"</br> Salary : "+value.salary);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```